# How I know toggleButton is checked or not checked

Tags: android

How I know toggleButton is checked or not checked.
please answer to my question becouse I need it.Thank all

xml:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

java:

```
public class Setting extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-togglebutton-example.html#.VelcWGSqpBc

Comment: when do you want to know the state of the ToggleButton? in `onCreate` ??

Answer (score 4):

Check Responding to Button Presses at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

Using xml attribute

```
android:checked="true"
```